# How to store an instance of UIImage in a var in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a filter function in `ViewControlller.swift` that filters the image of the `photoImageView`, which is also stored in `ViewControlller.swift`. The problem is that the color filter is applying to the result of the previous filtered image instead of the original image. How can I store `photoImageView` in an `originalImage` var to apply the filter to that instead?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func slideFilter(_ sender: UISlider) {

        var hueFilter = Double(sender.value)
        hueFilter = hueFilter.rounded(toPlaces: 2)

        //create image to filter
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)

        //Create a random color to apply
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: hueFilter]

        //Apply filter to image
        let filteredImage = inputImage!.applyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", parameters: randomColor)     

        let renderImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, from: filteredImage.extent)

        // Reflect the change back in the interface
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: renderImage!)
    }
}
```

When I try to store an instance of the variable `photoImageView` in ViewController, I get this error `Cannot use instance member 'photoImageView' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Comment: `var img: UIImage?`

Comment: when I try to store an instance of the variable `photoImageView` in ViewController I get this error `Cannot use instance member 'photoImageView' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Comment: "_When I try to store an instance of the variable photoImageView"_ What is stopping you from using the `photoImageView` variable? Why do you need another one?

Comment: Because in the last line of the filter function `photoImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: renderImage!)`. `photoImageView` changes to the filtered version. So if I use `photoImageView` as the input image for the filter the filter will change a filtered version of an image and not the original.

Comment: I would look up ‘Global Variables’ and ‘Local Variables’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store an instance of the variable `photoImageView` in the `ViewController`. You can, however, store an instance of the variable `photoImageView` within a method like `viewDidLoad()`.

Just use a breakpoint after the line:

```
let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)
```

See what is the value of the `inputImage`. Is this the image you want to operate upon?

Because if the `inputImage` is not correct, the final result will also be incorrect.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So would that look something like this `func storeImage() -> CIImage {
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!) return inputImage
    }`  if that is the case. wouldn't that just reassign `inputImage` every time the function is called?

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

You simply just create the `inputImage` variable outside of any method in `ViewController`. That way any methods can call it.

Set the value for `inputImage` in `viewDidLoad()`(and any place where you'll be changing the image). So the filter function can access the image.

End result:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    var inputImage:CIImage? 


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)


    }


    @IBAction func slideFilter(_ sender: UISlider) {

        var hueFilter = Double(sender.value)
        hueFilter = hueFilter.rounded(toPlaces: 2)

        //Create a random color to apply
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: hueFilter]

    //Apply filter to image
    let filteredImage = inputImage!.applyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", parameters: randomColor)     

    let renderImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, from: filteredImage.extent)

        // Reflect the change back in the interface
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: renderImage!)
    }
}
```